# Embed the same angular app in bootstrap modal dialog

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-bootstrap

I have huge angular app, with a lot of states. Now the idea is on clicking a button to open bootstrap uibModal dialog with the same angular app embedded and state set to the specific one. Also on dialog open user will have ability to go from one state to another just like in the main angular app. While user change states in modal instance state in main app is not affected. Is this possible using angular?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ui-router-extras](http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/example/stickymodal/#/people/managers)
Just create two named ui-view `<div ui-view="main"></div>` and `<div ui-view="modal"></div>` and pass common pages to main and modal dialogs to modal ui-view. Also You need to mark state as `sticky: true` if modal dialogs should opened in this state.